# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Part 1' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql

code in C# :-

```
private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Add_job_card.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        con.Open();
        s = "insert into Auto_Part_Details (Items_No, Job_Card, Value_Part, Auto_Parts_id) values (@Items_No, @Job_Card, @Value_Part,@Auto_Parts_id )";
        sd=new SqlCommand(s,con);
        sd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items_No", dgv_Add_job_card.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        sd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job_Card", dgv_Add_job_card.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        sd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value_Part", dgv_Add_job_card.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        sd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Auto_Parts_id", dgv_Add_job_card.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        sd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

the error in the line :-

```
sd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Auto_Parts_id", dgv_Add_job_card.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
```

this line is a combo box , table is :- Auto_Parts_id (int),
Auto_Part_desc (varchar(50))

and this form have the data grid view that display data only and after that i add all data i insert it in data grid view to database.

my code that display data in data grid view is :-

```
private void btn_Add_Job_card_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Validation_Add_Job_card_order();
        if (validate == true)
        {
            DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
            // = dt.Rows.Count + 1;
            r[0] = dt.Rows.Count + 1;
            //r[0] = txt_Items_No.Text;
            r[1] = txt_Job_card.Text;
            r[2] = txt_Value_Part.Text;
            r[3] = CB_Auto_parts.Text;
            r[4] = x;
            r[5] = CB_Providers_desc.Text;
            r[6] = CB_Hand_installation.Text;
            r[7] = txt_Notes.Text;

            dt.Rows.Add(r);
            dgv_Add_job_card.DataSource = dt;
            ClearText();

            txt_Total_Values.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Add_job_card.Rows
                                     where row.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                                     select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you know the data types, don't use `AddWithValue()`; specify the type.

Comment: According to your error, your `Auto_Parts_Id` column is an `int`, but the value you're trying to insert is a string ("Part 1"). You can't insert that into that column.

Comment: i know that but this value is combo box how i pass it into the database

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `Auto_Parts_id` column in your table is an integer type, but you're trying to insert the value "`Part 1`" which is a string, and cannot implicitly be converted to an integer.

In your `btn_Add_Job_card_Click` method, you're setting the following:

```
r[3] = CB_Auto_parts.Text;
```

...and then using this when doing your insert:

```
sd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Auto_Parts_id", dgv_Add_job_card.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
```

If you want the ID instead of the text, you could perhaps store this in your datarow as well, and use that as your parameter value instead of the text.

Comment: this CB_Auto_parts. is combo box i used this code to display the value  that i choose in grid view an i want insert this value to data base